# HTTP Request Failing in Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, http

My ASP.NET web app is interacting with an API and making calls to various endpoints.

When I hit the endpoints through Postman it's quick and successful. When I run the app locally it also works as expected. However, when I publish the app to Azure I'm having issues hitting the API and it's very inconsistent.

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. When it fails the call will hang up for a few seconds and then I get the following exception:
**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**

What I've come to notice through trial-and-error is that if I wait for around 10 seconds or so after each request it works. I tried using Thread.Sleep(10000) and Task.Delay(10000) to simulate me waiting the 10 seconds but those are causing issues (receiving the same connection attempt failed error).

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Construct POST Request
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Global.api + "/token");

                req.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                //Do POST Request
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        //Store data retrieved from POST request
                        string strContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        Token token = await content.ReadAsAsync<Token>();
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Comment: You need to read [You're using HttpClient wrong and it's destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). I'm not sure it will solve your issue, but it's definitely a cause for concern and you need to adjust.

Comment: When I try using that method I get the following error on the second API call: This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.

Comment: Are you doing multi threading or some other way of reusing your HttpClient?

Comment: I have a button that hits an endpoint of an API and another button that hits a different endpoint of the same API. In the button click events an async task method is being called that contains the call the to the API with http client object.

Comment: Adding request.Headers.Accept.Clear(); resolved that issue and it does seem a little faster but it still hangs up if I hit the same end point two or three times and gives the A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time error.